# Draw and remove a bitmap icon on canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am developing an app where the user can mark a damage icon on a car. The car here is basically an image and the damage icon is also an image. I am able to draw an image, where the user touches the car, using this code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btn_save, btn_resume;
    private ImageView iv_canvas;
    private Bitmap baseBitmap;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private Paint paint;
    public Bitmap bt;
    public Bitmap ct;
    boolean ismove = false;
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 50;
    int i = 0;
    private float x = 0;

    public HashMap<String, String> testholdmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // The initialization of a brush, brush width is 5, color is red
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        iv_canvas = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_canvas);

        iv_canvas.setOnTouchListener(touch);

        bt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.damage_mark_r_ic);
    }

    private View.OnTouchListener touch = new OnTouchListener() {
        // Coordinate definition finger touch
        float startX;
        float startY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            // Press the user action
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // The first drawing initializes the memory image, specify the
                // background is white
                if (baseBitmap == null) {
                    baseBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            R.drawable.b_ferrari_f152_000_0000).copy(
                            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                    canvas = new Canvas(baseBitmap);

                }
                // Recording began to touch point coordinate
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                break;
            // The user's finger on the screen of mobile action
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                float stopX = event.getX();
                float stopY = event.getY();
                if (startX == stopX) {

                    canvas.drawBitmap(bt, startX, startY, paint);

                    // The pictures to the ImageView
                    iv_canvas.setImageBitmap(baseBitmap);
                } else if (startX - stopX > 50 || stopX - startX > 50) {

                    baseBitmap = null;
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

}
```

My problem is figuring out how to remove this icon if it already drawn. I want it to function this way: I draw a damage icon on `x,y` position, and if the user clicks on `x,y` position again, then this damage icon will be removed.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Ref link 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rany.accidentreport.en&hl=en                            , i want same functionality like this app , for drawing damage icon on vehicle , i am able to draw an icon , but unable to remove ,

Comment: I'd recommend using a custom view and handling what is drawn on the canvas in onDraw(). You could manage the bitmaps that are drawn on the canvas at that point. I am sure you could do it this way, but it would likely get more convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
```

or

```
overlayBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

This sets an existing Bitmap to all transparent.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be like follows : 
Every time the user click on image - store the damge bounds (x,y,w,h) in list
and Draw it on the canvas
If user click again at the same damage image - remove it from list and redraw(clean canvas - Canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE)) everything again : the car and remaining images in the list

Comment: Seems like good, i just want to know how can i redraw(clean canvas) everything. what method i have to use , i am beginner of paint and canvas.